# How can I unbind an event for an element which comes with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

My javascript binds an event to a specific element like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.element-class', function() {
   binding_function();
}
```

I need to bind this way, since the element is on the content which comes with AJAX.

I tried to unbind:

```
$(".element-class").unbind();
```

But this doesn't work. How can I unbind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution.

```
$(document).off('click', '.tab-more-link');
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `.off`, it's the counterpart of `.on`, you can find the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/off/ . `.unbind` is the counterpart of `.bind`, so that didn't work here.

Comment: Thanks but didn't work for me. When I click a button, I set click event for that element. When I close the popup and click that button again, my on click adds that function again. I want to prevent somehow, this is why I try to "off" previously declared events first.

$(".element-class").data("events") also returns undefined where it's not actually.

Comment: Well, all I can say is that .off is the function you need to do this with, not sure where your specific mistake is then.